# What is fresh preserving?

Tags: food-preservation, canning

What kind of canning does *fresh preserving* refer to, or is it an all-encompassing sort of thing (e.g. water bath canning, pressure canning, freeze-canning, lacto-fermenting, etc.)?

I see the term used when you go to buy canning jars on Amazon and such (as well as at freshpreserving.com, obviously).

Comment: Does the website itself not explain their own term? I've personally never heard it but I don't do much canning.

Comment: @Catija I have not discovered a definition on the website, including in the FAQs (but it's not the only place that uses the term, and the website discusses multiple forms of canning—it's ambiguous whether or not these forms of canning are in association with 'fresh preserving'). Here's an example on Amazon where it uses the term: https://www.amazon.com/Ball-Quart-Jar-Wide-Mouth/dp/B00CNHCDR6/ (i.e. 'fresh preserve and store up to 1 year').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shule, I read over a **lot** on that site plus checked a number of other sites. It *seems* that the company that makes Ball® lids and glass jars for canning has coined the term 'fresh preserving' to refer to canning done either by boiling water bath immersion and by pressure canning. Included in these two methods are jams, chutneys and relishes, and pickles along with canned fruits and vegetables (and even meat and fish using pressure canning). Freezer jams are also included since Ball's jars and lids are used. They don't include lacto-fermenting but seem to refer only to fruits and vegetables, other than dehydrating.

I find it amusing that so many methods relating to foods - such as growing your own produce (plant or animal based), baking and cooking, as well as various methods of preserving food - has become 'fashionable. People who can see profit in this are jumping on the bandwagon. I used all these methods, except for cheese-making, so I could provide good tasting nutritious food for my family at far less cost than buying from a store. It's spoiled me as I now find commercially prepared foods (even the costly 'good tasting' stuff) bland and boring. So all the more power to younger ones setting out to learn how!